# Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmType: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: odata

Our service is using ODataV4 to call other service. We are occasionally seeing following exception in Production. We are making GET calls. Can you please suggest what should we be verifying/checking to root cause this error?
We are using 6.16 version of OData.Client

*System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal(IEdmStructuredType edmBaseType, Type type, PropertyInfo[] keyProperties, Boolean isEntity, Nullable`1 hasProperties)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmType(Type type)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.TypeResolver.ResolveExpectedTypeForReading(Type clientClrType)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateMaterializerForMessage(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Type materializerType, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.MaterializeAtom..ctor(ResponseInfo responseInfo, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.CreateMaterializer(ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ProcessResult[TElement](ProjectionPlan plan)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.EndExecute[TElement](IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.Management.Services.OData.Client.ODataServiceContextV4.<>c__DisplayClass45_0`1.b__1(IAsyncResult result)*